# Swap these two columns without using update in Oracle sql?

Tags: oracle

```
Ename     sex
ABC       male
Def       female
```

Swap between male & female.

Output should be

```
Male ABC
Female DEF
```

Thanks in advance!
Preparing for Interview.

Comment: I just made a screenshot of this question because I'm afraid it might disappear.

Comment: you want to switch from male to female?  Not sure SO can help

Comment: I was hoping formatting might help in some way, but sadly not. You don't even seem to know if you're swapping values or just displaying the columns in a different order. I really don't know what you're asking. I'm almost afraid to ask, but what have you tried?

Comment: Trying to get last name and first name and concatinating it. output should be ABC MALE

Comment: That's a third contradictory requirement; you don't have first/last name, and that's not what you said the output should be originally. Please take some time to edit your question into something coherent and answerable, including showing what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. I tried like this select lastname || firstname from emp. There are two columns firstname and lastname. I want to swap the data in those two columns like if it has Sharath Dandin. The output should be Dandin Sharath.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you have a table defined like:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
 (ENAME  VARCHAR2(20),
  SEX    VARCHAR2(6));
```

and that you have the following rows in it:

```
ENAME          SEX
ABC            male
Def            female
```

I'll further assume that the output in your question was the result of executing

```
SELECT * FROM EMP
```

Now, to answer your question - to get SEX first, then ENAME, try the following:

```
SELECT SEX, ENAME FROM EMP
```

If you're trying to concatenate the values of SEX and ENAME so you get back a single column try

```
SELECT SEX || ' ' || ENAME AS SEX_AND_NAME FROM EMP
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as below: Assuming table name is `EMP`

```
UPDATE TABLE EMP
SET ENAME = SEX,
    SEX = ENAME;
```

This will swap the values of the columns `ename` and `sex` not the column position.